# Django CMS saving data twice to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I created django-cms plugin, hook it multiple times on page. When I'm saving data to database,everything is saved twice. For the first time when i hit save button and after when i'm publishing page, is that normal for django-cms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior — draft/published version.

When you publish a page, all the plugins are copied, so you can continue editing a draft version without publishing it live.